# Angular NodeJs Remove Item from res.json();

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a data :

```
[{"_id":"sensor-2","sensor":{"arus":0.12666666666666665,"intensitas":55.333333333333336,"tanggal":"2018-08-06T03:14:58.885Z"}}]
```

I got the data from "res.json();" function, quest is how can i remove the "_id":"sensor-2".??

note: i use mongodb

what i expect:

```
[{"sensor":{"arus":0.12666666666666665,"intensitas":55.333333333333336,"tanggal":"2018-08-06T03:14:58.885Z"}}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{"_id":"sensor-2","sensor":{"arus":0.12666666666666665,"intensitas":55.333333333333336,"tanggal":"2018-08-06T03:14:58.885Z"}}];

delete data[0]._id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObj = {'test' : {'key1' : 'value', 'key2': 'value'}}
```

can I remove 'key1' so it becomes:

```
{'test' : {'key2': 'value'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the _id field from the results by setting its exclusion  to 0 in the query, as in the following example:

```
db.inventory.find({"username": uname},{ _id: 0 } )
```